# Generated variable results in wrong result

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have the following code:

```
$fut1 = 9814;
$Awaarde = 8304;
$Bwaarde = 5111;

$arrayAantallen = array("A", "B");

foreach ($arrayAantallen as $letter)
{
        $lijstMijnWaardes .= 'number_format(((round(' . ${$letter."waarde"} . ', -2))/1000), 1) + ';
}

$waarde = $lijstMijnWaardes + number_format(((round($fut1, -2))/1000), 1);
```

The result of $waarde is 9.8 (the value of $fut1), but I expect 23.2 (9.8+8.3+5.1).

Any idea? Thank you in advance!

edit: when I echo $lijstMijnWaardes, that result seems te be correct:

number_format(((round(8304, -2))/1000), 1) + number_format(((round(5111, -2))/1000), 1) +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above requirement, Try this,

```
$fut1 = 9814;
$Awaarde = 8304;
$Bwaarde = 5111;

$arrayAantallen = array("A", "B");

foreach ($arrayAantallen as $letter)
{
        $lijstMijnWaardes += number_format(((round(${$letter."waarde"}, -2))/1000), 1);
}

$waarde = $lijstMijnWaardes + number_format(((round($fut1, -2))/1000), 1);
```

Problem with your Code:

in the line `$lijstMijnWaardes .= 'number_format(((round(' . ${$letter."waarde"} . ', -2))/1000), 1) + ';` you are concatenating strings not forming an equation.

Advice:

Instead of forming the complete equation try performing that equation in every step.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of formating each digit, format the result.

```php
$fut1 = 9814;
$Awaarde = 8304;
$Bwaarde = 5111;

foreach (["A", "B"] as $letter) {
    $fut1 += ${$letter."waarde"};
}

echo  number_format(((round($fut1, -2))/1000), 1);
```

In addition, you may also want to initialize your variables before using them.

```php
PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $lijstMijnWaardes
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Steven. It is better, but in my case I have to round first and then sum the values.